# Best practice for showing Stripe billing history?

Tags: api, stripe-payments, billing

What's the best way to show Stripe invoices to a subscriber of an App -

A. store each recurring invoice as a charge in my db, then display them in a list

B. just call the Stripe API to show a list of invoices?

At the moment, I only store 1 record for a subscription, and update the expiry date in my db when the subscription renews.

Would it be better to store each recurring payment as an individual record, and then show a list of previous invoices, or just call the Stripe API instead?

Comment: They'd both work just fine. It's a trade off you'd need to make between the reduced complexity of retrieving from the external API, versus the increased latency it introduces and dependency on the external API being up. I think I would choose some hybrid where each time an invoice is paid I store a summary(maybe just the total amount, or a link to the [Stripe PDF](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-invoice_pdf)) and use that to power my frontend, with the option to retrieve the full invoice from the API if the customer wants more detail.

Comment: Another option is to redirect the customer to https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/customer-portal to let them see their past billing history.

Comment: @karllekko I had no idea that existed! thanks for sharing - that looks like a faster way to do it